# d3.js scatter plot don't redraw on transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition, scatter-plot

I have a line chart with transitions which I have added tool-tips. This works fine for the first department, but as soon as I change departments from the drop-down menu the scatter plot part of the chart isn't redrawn (the line updates as it should). I'm probably missing something fundamental here but when I have looked at examples I think I have got the right idea. Anybody see whats wrong with my code?

Update - removed the complete code. When I fire this in the console I get the desired change. But it doesn't work in my update function. And that I have a hard time understanding :)

```
focus.selectAll("circle")
.data(dataFilter)
    .attr("fill","blue")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.datum); })       
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.Kvot); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it - when I put in it's own update function and called it after the transition it seems to work. Anybody can explain why I can't put it in the other function? I guess it has something to do with the transition but don't know.

```
function update_circles() {
focus.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataFilter)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.datum); })       
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.Kvot); });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the `transition` method:

```
// Make the changes
focus.select("#Main").transition().duration(750)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width+3) + "," + y(yMain) + ")")
    .text(sec);
```

More on [transitions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions) in the official documentation. Regards,

Comment: I add it earlier so that part works (var focus = d3.select("body").transition();) It's the last part of the update-function that doesn't work, which deals with the dots.

Comment: I think that the part with the dots is also missing the `transition()` method.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to add it but it still gives me Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Can you post all the code? or better, create a fiddle or jsBin to isolate the problem?

Comment: All the code should be no problem, a fiddle is a bit more complicated since I'm running this on a quite large dataset. I'm wondering if it's something with the circle .enter, .update and .exit phases that I don't handle correctly (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)

Comment: I can change the circles from the console but not when calling my update-function. And for me that's weird but I guess I'm missing something fundamental here. I guess I need to: 1) Replace the old data binded to the elements 2) re-calculate the cy and cx